# use a single static_transform_publisher for multiple sensors

Tags: ros, sonar, static-transform-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I just started using ros to build a sonar sensor array composed of 16 sensors. I was wondering if there is a way to use a single static_transform_publisher to broadcast all the sensors frames to tf instead of creating a node for each sensors, which i think would introduce some overhead (16 processes vs. 1).

Please correct me if i'm wrong, or suggest an alternative solution to static_transform_publisher if it isn't the best way to do this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10771/use-a-single-static_transform_publisher-for-multiple-sensors/) by [akhernar](https://answers.ros.org/users/914/akhernar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @arebgun mentioned you can publish them all manually.  Or if you create a [URDF](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf)  and use [robot_state_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_state_publisher) it will publish them all for you.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-31**:
What do you mean it can't find the frames?  I suggest you ask a new question explaining what you did and what errors you get.

**Comment by [akhernar](https://answers.ros.org/users/914/akhernar/) on 2011-07-30**:
I tried this solution, but TransformListener can't find the frames I defined in the URDF file, while they show up correctly in tf_monitor and tf_echo...

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-07-29**:
Completely forgot about robot_state_publisher and URDF. I think that would be the best long term solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could just write a single node that publishes all 16 TF transforms from one process. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29) on how to  write a TF broadcaster in C++, or you can use static_transform_publisher source code as an example.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-07-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-29**:
if you look at the source of the static transform publisher all the work is done by a helper class.